# Did I install Firefox right and safely?

Tags: security, firefox

I didn't realize firefox could be downloaded inside of OS so I went online and found this code to type in the terminal.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install firefox
```

Is there any chance I got a malware version?

Answer (score 2):

You actually did install Firefox the safe way inside the OS. However, you used the command line instead of a graphical frontend. So no worries, there is nothing wrong with your Firefox installation, both alternatives have the same result.

Under elementary OS / Linux often "there is more than one way to do it…"

Comment: NP. You might want to accept the answer if it has solved your problem and comment there.